# Extjs 7 - How to get total from response header for pagination in grid ( ajax store )

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to set total from response header
or
add total to loaded data manually

```
store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            pageSize: globals.settings.items_per_page,
            fields: ['AccountNumber', 'Pan', 'OfflineFactId', 'TransactionJalaliDate', 'BranchDescription', 'GroupCode', 'GroupDescription'],
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: newUrl.replace(/{accountId}/g, account.AccountNumber),
                limitParam: 'pageSize',
                pageParam: 'pageNumber',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'result.generalResult',
                    totalProperty: 'result'
                }
            },
            autoLoad: true
        })
```

1. totalProperty is not my point
2. pagination is important for me

I try Docs ( pagingtoolbar, store, grid ,.... )
but i can't find anything useful

Comment: Where exactly do you have the total number of records in the response?

Comment: I have a response header. "X-Pagination"

Comment: You can create your own reader and use [`getResponseData`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/classic/Ext.data.reader.Reader.html#method-getResponseData) function to get pagination data from the header and transform it the way as Ext JS needs it.

Comment: thanks,
I finally use "beginprocessresponse" listener in proxy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found my answer. "beginprocessresponse" listener!

```
store: Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        pageSize: globals.settings.items_per_page,
        fields: ['AccountNumber', 'Pan', 'OfflineFactId', 'TransactionJalaliDate', 'BranchDescription', 'GroupCode', 'GroupDescription'],
        proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
            url: newUrl.replace(/{accountId}/g, account.AccountNumber),
            limitParam: 'pageSize',
            pageParam: 'pageNumber',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'result.generalResult',
                totalProperty: 'result.total'
            },
            listeners: {
                beginprocessresponse: function (store, response, operation) {
                    var totalPages = JSON.parse( response.getAllResponseHeaders()['x-pagination'] ).TotalRecords;
                    response.responseJson.result.total = totalPages;
                }
            }
        },
        autoLoad: true,

    })
```